# IP addresses and detection of bot/spam traffic

Tags: proxy, ip, subnet

I am trying to detect bot traffic to an application using a list of session ips.

The simplistic solution would be to find occurrences of identical ips and if the number of these are beyond a threshold, we could say that that traffic is coming from a bot.

I got myself thinking and doing some research and was questioning:

Could traffic coming from a single IP be coming from multiple users hiding behind a subnet or proxy? In which case definitely not being a bot?

(also i dont really understand how subnetting or proxies work, so be gentle.)

Answer (score 0):

there is more than just visit from IP, and its possible to get different visitors from the same IP (especially if visitor is using dial-up connection)

The way I would catch bots are with process of elimination from obvious to probable

- if userAgent is empty
- if userAgent is short or not descriptive
- if userAgent contains some obvious signatures or rogue bots that I
  don't want accessing my site
- if visitor's average pageview stay on the page is less than 3 sec its
  a bot

in this case I bounce the hit

and then not so obvious

I record a ip, timestamp and userAgent of every visit for 30 min.  and compare every new visit to the pool.

- If IP is accessing the site too quickly, most likely its a bot
- if IP is accessing the site with different userAgents is probably a
  bot

in this case I preset captcha